# python/sqlite3 query with column name to JSON

Tags: python, sqlite

i want to return a sql query output with column name as json,
to create an table on client-side.
But i have not found a solution for this.

my code:

```
json_data = json.dumps(c.fetchall())
return json_data
```

like this output:

```
{
                "name" : "Toyota1",
                "product" : "Prius",
                "color" : [
                  "white pearl",
                  "Red Methalic",
                  "Silver Methalic"
                ],
                "type" : "Gen-3"
}
```

does anyone know a solution?

Comment: How does your table represent an array in the `color` column? As far as I can tell sqlite does not have any array types (unless you encode them in a blob), so the color is probably constructed from multiple rows/tables.

Comment: The row color shows alle three points , this is not problem..

Answer (score 1):

Your code only returns the values. To also get the column names you need to query a table called 'sqlite_master', which has the sql string that was used to create the table.

```
c.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE " \
          "tbl_name='your_table_name' AND type = 'table'")
create_table_string = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

This will give you a string from which you can parse the column names:

```
"CREATE TABLE table_name (columnA text, columnB integer)"
```